# C# UDP Server loop maxing CPU

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, udp, cpu-usage

I have looked just about all over Google, and even here on Stack overflow, but I cannot seem to find the solution I'm looking for. I am testing my programming skills remaking Pong using MonoGame for C# and I'm trying to make this multiplayer with both UDP Clients and a UDP Server. I'm going with "the perfect client-server model" idea where the server handles all the calculations, while the game client just receives data from the server and displays it on the screen. Unfortunately I have had past issue working with programming UDP Servers. I have a loop in which I receive a datagram, than begin listening for another. I use Asynchronous calls because in my mind that is what would work the best for client and server. **Main** code looks something like this: (I'm going to cut out the bit that won't affect CPU, and show only the networking.)

```
    static void Main()
    {
        //Initialize
        Console.Title = "Pong Server";
        Console.WriteLine("Pong Server");
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        //Bind socket
        EndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 25565);
        Console.WriteLine("Binding to port 25565");
        serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);

        //Listen
        Console.WriteLine("Listening on {0}.", localEndPoint);

        //Prepare EndPoints
        EndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        //Recive Data...
        rcvPacket = new byte[Data.Size];
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(rcvPacket, 0, Data.Size, SocketFlags.None, ref clientEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(Receive), null);
    }
```

And then in the **Receive(IAsyncResult ar)** Method:

```
    static void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //Prepare EndPoints
        EndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        //End
        int PacketSize = serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref clientEndPoint);

        //<Handle Packet Code Here>

        //Receive Loop
        rcvPacket = new byte[Data.Size];
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(rcvPacket, 0, Data.Size, SocketFlags.None, ref clientEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(Receive), null);
    }
```

What this code looks like is that it will wait until a packet is received, than listen for another one, which will halt this "listener" thread, being asynchronous. Anyway thanks for reading my question and hopefully I'll get to the bottom of this.

Oh by the way, here is an image of one of my 4 cores getting maxed out. (Yes I'm currently debugging it.)
[image: Debugging Pong Server.exe; Maxing one of 4 CPU Cores]

Comment: When the packet is received in the **Receive(IAsyncResult ar)** Method it listens for another one. At the bottom of the two code snippets, you can see the listener, the second snippet is the "loop"

Comment: I edited the original post to make it easier to see the loop. **Receive(ar)** gets called from the **Main()** method (Command line app) and at the end of **Receive(ar)** it calls the **Receive(ar)** method once more, to continue to listen for packets.

Comment: Pause it in the debugger & look at the call stack to see what it's busy doing.

Comment: What size is `Data.Size`? If it's `0` you'll get the behavior that you describe.

Comment: @jgauffin Data.Size is a constant variable for my Data structure, I parse the datagram to the Data type, and vice versa to send and receive data to and from the server, but that's pretty obvious. The value of Data.Size is 21

Comment: what packetsize do you get back?

Comment: I think the problem is in the code you cut out. As the way it is written now the program would just open and close itself. I would bet money that the 100% cpu is from whatever you are doing after `serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(` in `static void Main()` to keep the program from closing.

Comment: Well yeah that might be it. I have a bool value called alive that will keep the program from finishing. I use while(alive) {} but I use that loop to do the calculations that the game needs such as updating paddle positions, calculating the ball's vectors and whatnot, so it's not just an empty loop.

Comment: It may not be empty but if there is no sleeps or yields it will certainly use 100% of a CPU core (if there is no IO requests involved). Add that code in to your question and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Alright. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Thanks Scott! It worked! Answered my own question, with picture proof. Thanks a lot for all the help! It's MUCH appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding **Thread.Sleep(1)** call to the update loop fixed not only the CPU usage in the original problem, but it also made the the code executed in the update loop behave better. inside the **while(alive)}{ }** where I keep track of the elapsed time and total time, I insert the sleep call.

The value seems to be needed **at least 1**.

[image: 0 CPU Usage!]

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Initialize
        Console.Title = "Pong Server";
        Console.WriteLine("Pong Server");
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        //Bind socket
        EndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 25565);
        Console.WriteLine("Binding to port 25565");
        serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);

        //Listen
        Console.WriteLine("Listening on {0}.", localEndPoint);

        //Prepare EndPoints
        EndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        //Recive Data...
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(rcvPacket, 0, Data.Size, SocketFlags.None, ref clientEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveFrom), null);

        //Initialize TimeSpans
        DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime Start = Now;
        DateTime LastUpdate = Now;
        TimeSpan EllapsedTime;
        TimeSpan TotalTime;

        //Create Physics Objects
        Paddle1 = new Physics2D();
        Paddle2 = new Physics2D();
        Ball = new Physics2D();

        //Loop
        while (alive)
        {
            Now = DateTime.Now;
            TotalTime = Now - Start;
            EllapsedTime = Now - LastUpdate;
            LastUpdate = Now;
            Update(EllapsedTime, TotalTime);

            //Add Sleep to reduce CPU usage;
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        //Press Any Key
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: What is `Update` doing that you need to call it so often?

Comment: It's playing the game technically, if you could imagine the game loop, but the game loop is on the server, and the server tells the client where everything is.m

Answer (score -1):

From MSDN documentation:

> Your callback method should invoke the **EndReceiveFrom** method. When your application calls BeginReceiveFrom, **the system will use a separate thread to execute the specified callback method, and it will block on EndReceiveFrom until the Socket reads data** or throws an exception. If you want the original thread to block after you call the BeginReceiveFrom method, use WaitHandle.WaitOne. Call the Set method on a T:System.Threading.ManualResetEvent in the callback method when you want the original thread to continue executing. For additional information on writing callback methods, see Callback Sample

From my understanding, you create the callback thread directly when you call BeginReceiveFrom.
Because you do not use EndReceiveFrom, you callback thread is executed, creating another thread , again and again ...

Use EndReceiveFrom to wait for the whole packet to be read, then your callback will repeat and start reading again. Watch out for thread safety I have no idea how you manage your data here.

Looking at that post could help : 
[Asynchronous TCP/UDP Server](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7226/is-this-implementation-of-an-asynchronous-tcp-udp-server-correct)

Comment: -1 He do not create a thread anywhere but specify the callback just like he should.

Comment: But the system execute the callback on a separate thread, so he creates one just by specifying a callback.

Comment: No, the system handles that thread. And it's only invoked either when something have been received, or if the buffer is full or due to an error.

Comment: The callback is the same method than where BeginReceive is called from. The documentation said that the callback will block on EndReceiveFrom, which here doesnt appear, therefore I would say the callback wont block.

Comment: His begin/end code is perfectly fine. I've used those methods and callbacks dozens of times. Have you? How he use them is not a problem. It's more probably the problem is what I said in my question comment.